# Ajax only works synchronously

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have this code that sets my ajax request :

```
function sendAjaxRequest() {
            ajax.open("post", "form.php", false);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = gotResponseFromServer();
            ajax.send(jsonObject);

        }
```

And this one php that executes the request :

```
    <?php
    require_once "database_connection.php";
    con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$db)  OR die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $decodedData = json_decode($data);


    //$verifyCode = md5(rand()."");
    $name = $decodedData->{'name'};
    $surname = $decodedData->{'surname'};
    $email = $decodedData->{'email'};
    $phone = $decodedData->{'phone'};
    $birthDate = $decodedData->{'birthDate'};
    $studies = $decodedData->{'studies'};
    $work = $decodedData->{'work'};
    $married = $decodedData->{'married'};
    $skills = $decodedData->{'skills'};
    $hobby = $decodedData->{'hobby'};
    $city = $decodedData->{'city'};
    $gender = $decodedData->{'gender'};
    $baptized = $decodedData->{'baptized'};
    $suggestions = $decodedData->{'suggestions'};
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Voluntari (_name, _surname, _email, _phone, _birthDate, ".
            "_studies, _work, _married, _skills, _hobby, _city, _gender, _baptized, _suggestions) ".
            "VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$email', '$phone', '$birthDate', '$studies', '$work', '$married',".
            "'$skills', '$hobby', '$city', '$gender', '$baptized', '$suggestions'  );";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    } else {
        //sendConfirmationMail();
        echo "added";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is that I can't make the ajax request asynchronously and I don't know why. If I do it synchronously, the form data gets added to the database  but if I do in in an asynchronous way, the `ajax.status` is always 0 and `ajax.readyState` is 1.

To change the request from asynchronous to synchronous I put `false` in here :

```
ajax.open("post", "form.php", false);
                              ^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I keep my request asynchronous and make my script work?

Comment: How did you defined `ajax`? Is it a jQuery var?

Comment: No it's XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Try with jQuery if feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the call to your function `gotResponseFromServer` returns another function, it should probably be

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = gotResponseFromServer;
```

i.e. you want to assign a function to onreadystatechange, not its return value.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here for example: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp you will see that the parameters get described like this:

`open(method,url,async)`
method: the type of request: GET or POST
url: the location of the file on the server
async: **true (asynchronous)** or false (synchronous)

To make your request asynchronous you will have to call `ajax.open("post", "form.php", true);`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's query.

Comment: Yeah..I know..But the thing is that the form doesn't get inserted into the database with async true